# is it possible to put that in a loop?

Tags: php, loops, mysqli

Is there a possibility to put that in a loop?

```
if (!empty($_POST["textDE"])) {
    $mysqli = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `l10n-strings` (`translationID`, `languageCode`, `text`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $mysqli->bind_param('iss', $l10id, $languageCodeDE, $textDE);
    $mysqli->execute();
}

if (!empty($_POST["textEN"])) {
    $mysqli = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `l10n-strings` (`translationID`, `languageCode`, `text`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $mysqli->bind_param('iss', $l10id, $languageCodeEN, $textEN);
    $mysqli->execute();
}

if (!empty($_POST["textES"])) {
    $mysqli = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `l10n-strings` (`translationID`, `languageCode`, `text`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $mysqli->bind_param('iss', $l10id, $languageCodeES, $textES);
    $mysqli->execute();
}

if (!empty($_POST["textFR"])) {
    $mysqli = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `l10n-strings` (`translationID`, `languageCode`, `text`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $mysqli->bind_param('iss', $l10id, $languageCodeFR, $textFR);
    $mysqli->execute();
}

if (!empty($_POST["textIT"])) {
    $mysqli = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `l10n-strings` (`translationID`, `languageCode`, `text`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $mysqli->bind_param('iss', $l10id, $languageCodeIT, $textIT);
    $mysqli->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$languages = array('DE', 'EN', 'ES', 'FR', 'IT');

foreach ($languages as $lang) {
    $langKey = 'text' . $lang;
    if (!empty($_POST[$langKey])) {
        $mysqli = $connect->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO `l10n-strings` (`translationID`, `languageCode`, `text`) ".
            "VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
        );
        $mysqli->bind_param(
            'iss',
            $l10id,
            ${'languageCode'.$lang},
            ${$langKey}
        );
        $mysqli->execute();
    }
}
```

[Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) make this easier, with a look-up array.

Also [disable register globals in your PHP configuration](http://www.php.net/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals), it is a security issue.

Comment: @Bob: no worries, we all have to start somewhere. ;-)

Comment: @hakre: The comment concerning the register globals was a good addition, but refactoring for a `$langKey` makes the code mis-match OPs (they don't reference `$_POST` in `bind_param()`, unless you're assuming that's a global--though I'm not sure why you'd bounce between `$_POST['var']` and `$var`).